# How do I redirect a form after submission to the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I want my form to be submitted, after submitting that values it should redirect to the form and display the values. I've tried many things... but no luck yet... 
So I've decided to post here. It should be like most of the edit fields, the stored value or the submitted value should appear.
This is my code:

```
<form method="post" name="contentUpload" action="insertContent.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
    <table>
        <tr id="small">
            <td>Category</td>
            <td>
                <select name="contentCategory">
                    <<option value="1">World</option>
                        <option value="2">Health/Env/Scn</option>
                        <option value="3">Travel</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="small">
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="contentTitle" size="80">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="small">
            <td>Writer</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="writer" size="80">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="small">
            <td>Upload Picture</td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="small">Display Mode</td>
            <td required>
                <input type="radio" name="status" value="Online" /> Online
                <input type="radio" name="status" value="Offline" /> Offline
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="small">Final Submission</td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="submitContent" value="Update">
                <input type="reset" name="resetContent" value="Reset">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
```

this is my addcontent.php

```
<?php include ( "./inc/connect.inc.php" ); ?>
<?php
session_start();
$target_dir = "new/Images/";
$file_name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(isset($_POST["submitContent"])) 
{
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) 
{
echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
$uploadOk = 1;
} 
else 
{
echo "File is not an image.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) 
{
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} 
else 
{
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
{
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} 
else 
{
echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}
if (isset($_POST['submitContent']))
{
$eid = $_SESSION['employeeId'];
$contentCategory = $_POST['contentCategory'];
$contentTitle = $_POST['contentTitle'];
$contentWriter = $_POST['writer'];
$displayMode = $_POST['status'];
$query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO contentdetails(employeeId,contentCategory,contentTitle,contentWriter,photo,displayMode,published_on) 
VALUES('$eid','$contentCategory','$contentTitle','$contentWriter',
'$file_name','$displayMode',NOW())");
}
?>
```

Comment: Explain the error or bad bhaviour encontered. Do not simply say it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your form tag leave the action="" tag empty.

```
<?php 
    // Remove session_start() from this file. It should be before any html.
    include 'insertContent.php';
    if (isset($_POST['submitContent'])) {
        foreach ($_POST as $p) {
            echo $p . "<br>";
        }
    }
?>
<form method="post" name="contentUpload" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: @ARIJITDASGUPTA Just put `value="<?php echo $_POST['contentTitle']; ?>"` for example in your HTML. As long as the form isn't submitted, this won't do anything. After that it will put the values back into the fields.

Comment: @icecub it's showing `value="<?php echo $_POST['contentTitle']; ?>"` in the field before submitting the value.... `<tr id="small">
   <td>Title</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="contentTitle" size="80" value="<?php echo $_POST['contentTitle']; ?>"> </td>
  </tr>`

Comment: <input type="text" name="contentTitle" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['contentTitle'])) ? $_POST['contentTitle'] : ''; ?>">

Comment: @ARIJITDASGUPTA happy to help.